# TypeError: callback is not a function at FSReqWrap.cb

Tags: node.js

I have created a small application, it is running good but while testing with some load the application use to stop by giving the following error:

```
TypeError: callback is not a function
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:212:19)
```

I am not finding any specific reason for the above `error`, my application developed using node express project and it will be listening on the specific port and whenever request come it uses the parameter coming from the `URL` and based on some logic it sends some text to another server using `UDP`.

Any help will be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Can you post that code here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To assure the quality of questions, please refer to the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) document on composing them.